# how to remove htmldocument.cs not found error in html agility pack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

class Response:

```
public string WebResponse(string url) //class through which i'll have link of website and will parse some divs in method of this class
{
    string html = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument(); //when code comes here it gives an error htmldocument.cs not found,and open window for browsing source
        WebClient client = new WebClient(); // even if i put htmlWeb there it still look for HtmlWeb.cs not found
        html = client.DownloadString(url); //is this from some breakpoint error coz i set only one in method where i am parsing,
        doc.LoadHtml(html);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        html = string.Empty;
    }

    return html; //please help me to remove this error using html agility pack with console application 
}
```

even if i make new project and run code it stuck here and i have added DLL too still it is giving me this error please help me to remove this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that error is sometimes because of version of you are using of Nuget html agility pack,update your nuget in the visual studio gallery then try installing html agility pack and run in your project

Comment: Thanx but im over it now,i am trying anglesharp

Answer (score 1):

WebResponse is an abstract class meaning it is a reserved word first of all. Second - In order to use WebResponse a class has to inherit from WebResponse ie.

```
public class WR : WebResponse
{
    //Code
}
```

Also. Your current code has nothing to with Html Agility Pack. If you want to load the html of a webpage into a HtmlDocument - do the following:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

try{
    var temp = new Uri(url);
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(temp);
    request.Method = "GET";
    using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            htmlDoc.Load(stream, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-9"));
        }
    }
}catch(WebException ex){
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Then in order to get nodes in the Html Document you have to use xPath like so:

```
HtmlNode node = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//body");
Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText);
```

Comment: please tell me what is "htmlDoc" in this line, "  htmlDoc.Load(stream, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-9"));"

Comment: That's your HtmlDocument, should be fairly obvious from the context of the post. HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

Comment: Remember to mark this as an correct answer if it helped you out.

Comment: your code works fine but when i come at this line "htmlDoc.Load(stream, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-9"));" means i will have to use Htmldocument htmldoc; as well and when i put Htmldocument in my try code it gives the same error or tell me how to load Html in something then i can apply my loops on that code, reply soon

Comment: The above code is meant to download the HTML from the website. You have to input the utl. htmlDoc then gives you a DOM that can be navigated with xPath. Have you downloaded HTML Agility Pack library?

Comment: it was really helpful, it is removed for now i cleaned solution and added html agility pack again, but please can u help i want to get only items of drop down list from Html, like Camera,Tv,Fashion and then have their links but don't want sub nodes of camera,tv, i just want the link of these camera,fashion. HtmlNodeCollection to select div and then foreach for all? or Select single node,? please explain

Comment: You have to be elegant. And design an appropriate xpath. I can't do that without the link to the page you're trying to scrape.

Comment: here it is (https://www.daraz.pk) i want to have links and names of main categories in the Dropdown at left side, Womens fashion men's fashion, these are 12, i got this in Htmlnodecollection it shows 12 but how do i save them i mean i should use console.writeLine() or what? or tell me any other way, please waiting for your reply

Answer (score 0):

You can try cleaning and re-building the solution.This may fix the issue.

Comment: looks a comment.